# Transmit commands in ASCII format STM32

Tags: format, ascii, stm32, transmitfile

I'm using STM32 discovery board to communicate to a device that takes ASCII commands.

I use `HAL_UART_TRANSMIT_IT` to send data, that works fine.

I want to send ASCII command XM3 to the device. When I use virtual port programs as realterm, I just click on ascii and put the baudrate, databitc etc etc and when I type in XM3 and click on +CR it send the command and it works fine, if CR is not included it doesent work.

When I try to do that from my MCU I use this code and it does not work, any ideas how to send ASCII commands in C via serial port?

```
char txD[3]="XM3";
__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1, UART_IT_TC);
HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)txD ,3);
```

When I send this to realterm it shows XM3 but when I send this to the device nothing happens.

I need to know how I send XM3 and a CR to the device.

Comment: `char txD[3]="XM3\n";` your device probably waits for the \n and `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1, (uint8_t *)txD ,strlen(txD));`

Comment: `char txD[] = "XM3\n";` of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send the command via *Realterm* and check the `+CR` option, *Realterm* does append a [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), i.e. ASCII Code `13`.

In order to reproduce this behavior in your code, you should define the command as follows:

```
char txD[4]="XM3\r";
```

Respectively, if the receiver also expects to receive a [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), i.e. ASCII Code `10`, you should define it as follows:

```
char txD[5]="XM3\r\n";
```